# Is a Site Search dependent on a view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

If I have 1 view called All with indexes, but the All view is greater than 5,000 records I assume a Site search on one of those 5,000 records would fail to find the item OR be unable to open the link for the list item ?

Also, if I create a folder and then sub folders is that one way of avoiding the 5,000 record limitation.  Thus, can I create a folder called 2018 and then Jan, Feb, Mar. etc. for the sub folders and the sub folders would be allowed a 5,000 view each ?

Comment: `would fail to find the item OR be unable to open the link for the list item`  Are you finding this to be the case? Or this is a hypothetical question?

Comment: hypothetical..thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint supports store 30,000,000 items per list. Check the [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits)

The List View Threshold is based on the list view and it is set to allow user to work with large list but keep good performance. The default of List View Threshold is 5000 items.

It will not cause the site search to fail.

To work around the limit, you can use folders to organize.

Information about [managing large lists and libraries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59).